# how to query metricbeat system cpu and memory data stored in elasticsearch 6.3

Tags: elasticsearch, system, metrics, metricbeat

i am using metricbeat on my servers to collect system metrics and store it in elasticsearch, and for some reason i do not want to use kibana to preview or get the data i want, for example i want to query cpu usage and memory usage from elasticsearch, i have did a lot of researches but i cannot find something clear that i can understand, 
i am using elastic 6.3
What i have done so far

```
http://localhost:9200/metricbeat*/_search
{
"took": 5,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 1830,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "RImkjWQBakcGABbiLI2H",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.128Z",
                "metricset": {
                    "name": "load",
                    "module": "system",
                    "rtt": 86
                },
                "system": {
                    "load": {
                        "1": 1.02,
                        "5": 0.95,
                        "15": 0.66,
                        "norm": {
                            "1": 0.255,
                            "5": 0.2375,
                            "15": 0.165
                        },
                        "cores": 4
                    }
                },
                "beat": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "version": "6.3.0"
                },
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "RYmkjWQBakcGABbiLI2I",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.129Z",
                "beat": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "version": "6.3.0"
                },
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                },
                "metricset": {
                    "rtt": 725,
                    "name": "memory",
                    "module": "system"
                },
                "system": {
                    "memory": {
                        "total": 3956293632,
                        "used": {
                            "bytes": 3824742400,
                            "pct": 0.9667
                        },
                        "free": 131551232,
                        "actual": {
                            "used": {
                                "pct": 0.7733,
                                "bytes": 3059421184
                            },
                            "free": 896872448
                        },
                        "swap": {
                            "total": 2147479552,
                            "used": {
                                "pct": 0,
                                "bytes": 0
                            },
                            "free": 2147479552
                        },
                        "hugepages": {
                            "used": {
                                "bytes": 0,
                                "pct": 0
                            },
                            "free": 0,
                            "reserved": 0,
                            "surplus": 0,
                            "default_size": 2097152,
                            "total": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "RomkjWQBakcGABbiLI2I",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.131Z",
                "metricset": {
                    "name": "filesystem",
                    "module": "system",
                    "rtt": 229
                },
                "system": {
                    "filesystem": {
                        "free": 0,
                        "files": 0,
                        "free_files": 0,
                        "type": "fuse.gvfsd-fuse",
                        "device_name": "gvfsd-fuse",
                        "mount_point": "/run/user/1000/gvfs",
                        "total": 0,
                        "available": 0,
                        "used": {
                            "bytes": 0,
                            "pct": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "beat": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "version": "6.3.0"
                },
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "R4mkjWQBakcGABbiLI2I",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.131Z",
                "metricset": {
                    "name": "filesystem",
                    "module": "system",
                    "rtt": 257
                },
                "system": {
                    "filesystem": {
                        "mount_point": "/",
                        "total": 28968488960,
                        "available": 19802587136,
                        "type": "xfs",
                        "device_name": "/dev/mapper/centos-root",
                        "free": 19802587136,
                        "free_files": 13836527,
                        "used": {
                            "pct": 0.3164,
                            "bytes": 9165901824
                        },
                        "files": 14151680
                    }
                },
                "beat": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "version": "6.3.0"
                },
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "SImkjWQBakcGABbiLI2I",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.131Z",
                "beat": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "version": "6.3.0"
                },
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                },
                "metricset": {
                    "name": "filesystem",
                    "module": "system",
                    "rtt": 263
                },
                "system": {
                    "filesystem": {
                        "free_files": 523961,
                        "device_name": "/dev/sda1",
                        "mount_point": "/boot",
                        "files": 524288,
                        "type": "xfs",
                        "total": 1063256064,
                        "available": 885817344,
                        "free": 885817344,
                        "used": {
                            "bytes": 177438720,
                            "pct": 0.1669
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "SYmkjWQBakcGABbiLI2I",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.131Z",
                "system": {
                    "cpu": {
                        "iowait": {
                            "pct": 0.001
                        },
                        "irq": {
                            "pct": 0
                        },
                        "softirq": {
                            "pct": 0.0021
                        },
                        "cores": 4,
                        "idle": {
                            "pct": 3.4226
                        },
                        "nice": {
                            "pct": 0
                        },
                        "user": {
                            "pct": 0.45
                        },
                        "system": {
                            "pct": 0.1243
                        },
                        "steal": {
                            "pct": 0
                        },
                        "total": {
                            "pct": 0.5774
                        }
                    }
                },
                "beat": {
                    "version": "6.3.0",
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain"
                },
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                },
                "metricset": {
                    "name": "cpu",
                    "module": "system",
                    "rtt": 357
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "SomkjWQBakcGABbiLI2I",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.131Z",
                "system": {
                    "uptime": {
                        "duration": {
                            "ms": 562000
                        }
                    }
                },
                "beat": {
                    "version": "6.3.0",
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain"
                },
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                },
                "metricset": {
                    "module": "system",
                    "rtt": 16,
                    "name": "uptime"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "S4mkjWQBakcGABbiLI2I",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.131Z",
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                },
                "beat": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "version": "6.3.0"
                },
                "metricset": {
                    "name": "fsstat",
                    "module": "system",
                    "rtt": 643
                },
                "system": {
                    "fsstat": {
                        "count": 3,
                        "total_files": 14675968,
                        "total_size": {
                            "free": 20688404480,
                            "used": 9343340544,
                            "total": 30031745024
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "TImkjWQBakcGABbiLI2I",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.131Z",
                "metricset": {
                    "name": "network",
                    "module": "system",
                    "rtt": 1057
                },
                "system": {
                    "network": {
                        "name": "lo",
                        "in": {
                            "errors": 0,
                            "dropped": 0,
                            "bytes": 260748,
                            "packets": 975
                        },
                        "out": {
                            "dropped": 0,
                            "packets": 975,
                            "bytes": 260748,
                            "errors": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "beat": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "version": "6.3.0"
                },
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "metricbeat-6.3.0-2018.07.12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "TYmkjWQBakcGABbiLI2I",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2018-07-12T08:38:23.131Z",
                "metricset": {
                    "rtt": 1087,
                    "name": "network",
                    "module": "system"
                },
                "system": {
                    "network": {
                        "name": "virbr0-nic",
                        "in": {
                            "errors": 0,
                            "dropped": 0,
                            "bytes": 0,
                            "packets": 0
                        },
                        "out": {
                            "errors": 0,
                            "dropped": 0,
                            "packets": 0,
                            "bytes": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "beat": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
                    "version": "6.3.0"
                },
                "host": {
                    "name": "localhost.localdomain"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

so for example if i want to query system cpu user/nice/system/ total

and memory total and used, also is there is a way to query data for example if i want to query cpu:user usage that are above 80% how to do it

appreciate your patience and help

Answer (score 2):

For memory you can query elasticsearch with:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  http://localhost:12001/metricbeat*/_search?pretty=true -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must": [{"range": {"system.memory.used.pct": {"gte": 0}}},{"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-1d","lte": "now/m"}}}]}}}'
```

For CPU you can query elasticsearch with:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  http://localhost:12001/metricbeat*/_search?pretty=true -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must": [{"range": {"system.process.cpu.total.norm.pct": {"gte": 0.80}}},{"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-1h","lte": "now/m"}}}]}}}'
```

You can change elasticsearch port, CPU and memory usage values according to your requirement. Refer to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/6.3/exported-fields-system.html) for more details.

Comment: Is that possible to get the result of both fields "system.process.cpu.total.norm.pct" and "system.memory.used.pct" in one query?